# Artifactory Generic Download - VSTS Task Failing

Tags: package, azure-devops, artifactory, azure-artifacts, jfrog-cli

I have set up a very basic task in a VSTS build definition with the following simple steps and objective:

1. Setup and successfully test an endpoint to our Artifactory repository.
2. Implement a VSTS "Artifactory Generic Download" Task to retrieve a single jar file from the Artifactory repository.
3. Drop the jar file in staging directory of the build agent.

The file spec source, based on an example from the JFrog website www.jfrog.com and set up as a Task Configuration is very basic and is depicted below:

[image]

Unfortunately, triggering this build job fails horribly with the below error and I simply can't figure out why it is failing. Would appreciate some help on this.

[image]

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue new build and share the log here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no artifacts were found and the task fails due to the configured "Fail task if no dependencies were downloaded" flag. If you wish to change this behavior, you can uncheck the flag in your task configuration.
As for the not downloaded artifacts, make sure a repository called "list" exists and a jar file exists in the provided pattern.
More information about file-specs can be found [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs).